# Can I get two different results from UNIX_TIMESTAMP in one query?

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

This seems an obvious thing but I'm just not sure about the correct answer.

If I use an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` command in a **single** mysql query, can I get two different results from `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`? That is, does the time change *during* one query?

**Example:**

```
UPDATE my_table SET
time1 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
...
...
time2 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
...
```

Is it possible that `time2` will be larger than `time1`?

(for anyone asking what good it is to set two columns to the same value - I'm using one for the time *added* and time *updated* so that I can sort just by one column)

If possible, provide some background information for your answer. Thanks!

Comment: If I remember correctly, MySQL has special column types for "created" and "last updated" that are handled automatically.

Comment: The question is:  **have you** seen this behavior on your system?

Comment: @Teetrinker, I'll take a look at it but I apply these times selectively, e.g. time _added_ might not be the same as time _created_ and time _updated_ might not be the same as the time of the last update of that row, so that won't crack this. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: @AJ, no I haven't seen it (yet) - I want to prevent later failures, that's why I'm asking beforehand.

Comment: Seems I can't edit my comment, so please have a look at this page for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html

Comment: The only way I remember to do UPDATE and INSERT in **one** query is to use ON DUPLICATE KEY. In that case, only one gets executed, so it's a non-issue. If there's another way, please provide full statement. My MySQL is rusty.

Comment: @Mel, I'm not trying to do `UPDATE` and `INSERT` in one query, I'm sorry if my question isn't clear. I just want to know if I can get two different results from `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` in one single query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL time & date functions return the time/date of the beginning of the statement, so if you do :

```
CREATE TABLE t ( x INT );
INSERT INTO t SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() FROM (10M rows table)  -- takes several seconds
SELECT DISTINCT x FROM t;
```

DISTINCT returns one value, which correspond to the time when the INSERT began executing.

Comment: Thanks for that! What does the 10M do? I don't think I've ever seen that in a sql command.

Comment: it's not SQL, it's English ;) i've used a 10 million rows table so the insert takes several seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the answer to your question. However, assuming your motivation is to get consistent timestamps when writing to the table, why not take the following approach: create a stored procedure. Inside the procedure, assign to a variable using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, and execute your `UPDATE` or `INSERT` query using the variable, rather than further calls to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. That way you are guaranteed the correct behaviour.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "My_Insert_Procedure" ()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN

DECLARE my_time DATETIME;
SET my_time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();

UPDATE my_table SET
time1 = my_time,
...
...
time2 = my_time,
...

END

CALL My_Insert_Procedure();
```

Comment: Hammerite, thanks for your suggestion. I'm using php with MySQL, so the possibility of assigning the unix timestamp to a variable and then putting it in the query occured to me. My question is really a theoretical one, if it is possible to do this directly in a single SQL query or not.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql unix_timestamp() is similar to now() - it returns time when the statement began to execute and is different to sysdate() which returns time when the function itself is executed.

```
CREATE TABLE test ( date datetime, tstamp int(11) );
INSERT INTO test VALUES( 0,0 ), ( 0,0 ), ( 0,0 );
UPDATE test SET date=sysdate(), tstamp=unix_timestamp() WHERE !sleep(2);
+---------------------+------------+
| date                | tstamp     |
+---------------------+------------+
| 2011-05-20 22:39:58 | 1305923996 |
| 2011-05-20 22:40:00 | 1305923996 |
| 2011-05-20 22:40:02 | 1305923996 |
+---------------------+------------+
```